# how to call xslt template to create new entry for each parsed tokens

Tags: parsing, xslt, while-loop

A job is to be posted in multiple locations. Each location must be treated separately, and the  job location field returns a long string of city, state values
Here is the code I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <source>
            <publisher>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!                      [CDATA[</xsl:text>Test INC.<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
            </publisher>
            <xsl:for-each select="body/row">
                <job>
                    <title>
                        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="field[3]/."/>
                        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
                    </title>
                    <referencenumber>
                        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="field[1]/."/>
                        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;  </xsl:text>
                    </referencenumber>
                    <city>
                        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="contains(field[34]/.,',')">
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(field[34]/.,',')"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="field[34]/."/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;   </xsl:text>
                    </city>
                    <state>
                        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:if test="contains(field[34]/.,',')">
                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-after(field[34]/.,','))"/>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
                    </state>
```

This is where I get stuck. The location field (34) if it returns a single location such as Atlanta, GA. - it parses the data and all is OK. But if I have two locations:
Atlanta, Ga., Chicago, IL.
How can I call the template again so that each location has it own entry.

Output should look like the following: Each location with it's own template.
How do you call the template for each parsed location value

```
<source>
  <publisher>
    <![CDATA[ Test INC. ]]>
  </publisher>
  <publisherurl>
    <![CDATA[ https://www.test.us/ ]]>
  </publisherurl>
  <job>
    <title>
      <![CDATA[ Transformation Manager ]]>
    </title>
    <referencenumber>
      <![CDATA[ 192 ]]>
    </referencenumber>
    <city>
      <![CDATA[ Atlanta ]]>
    </city>
    <state>
      <![CDATA[ GA. ]]>
    </state>
<source>
  <publisher>
    <![CDATA[ Test INC. ]]>
  </publisher>
  <publisherurl>
    <![CDATA[ https://www.test.us/ ]]>
  </publisherurl>
  <job>
    <title>
      <![CDATA[ Transformation Manager ]]>
    </title>
    <referencenumber>
      <![CDATA[ 192 ]]>
    </referencenumber>
    <city>
      <![CDATA[ Chicago ]]>
    </city>
    <state>
      <![CDATA[ IL. ]]>
    </state>
```

Comment: Well, how does the input XML look like exactly? Hopefully, if there is a need to distinguish two values, they are marked up separately. Or do you need to split up a string like `Atlanta, Ga., Chicago, IL` in XSLT 1.0?

Comment: Please (a) show us the input XML and (b) fix the expected output so it's well-formed XML.

Comment: The actual XML input looks like "Atlanta, Ga.; Chicago, IL."

The purpose is to split the string of cities, and then repeat the template for each different city listed. The template should return each location separately. Each template is allowed to display only 1 location at a time.

So yes, the locations must be parsed, but the part I'm confused on is the way to loop the file and retrieve the next location in the list.

I don't know how to describe it any other way.